# Why i am getting "name 'os' is not defined" error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, compiler-errors, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

[image]

Why i am getting this error? it should be work.Probally i'm missing something from my sight.
Before that same thing happen the for Classes.I tried rewrite and still same.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img_array = cv2.imread("Training/0/Training_233976.jpg")

img_array.shape

plt.imshow(img_array)

Datadirectory = "Training/"

Classes = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"]

for category in Classes:
    path = os.path.join(Datadirectory, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        plt.show()
        break
    break
```

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: You need to import the os library before calling any methods of that library. in the beginning of the code write `import os`

Comment: @yudhiesh yes.It gives an error like that.

Comment: @AshishJain  i was import the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
```

use this at beginning of your code or where you are importing other libraries and codes .

Answer (score -1):

I am formalizing in an answer, all you need to do is add a line at the top

import os